# A good synonymy for "list" as a PHP method?

Tags: php, reserved-words

I am building an application where the client provides `$_GET['task']` which is limited to `list`, `detail`, or `edit`, and in response the server will provide a list of available records for all IDs, the record for `$_GET['id']`, or a form to edit record `$_GET['id']`, respectively.

I would like the string provided by the client to directly match a method in a certain object and not have to map it as a one-off so that I and others will not get confused.

All works well except for `list` as it is a reserved word.

What is a good synonymy for "list" from both a general user's (since they will see it in the URL) and developers prospective (since they have to make it work)?

Comment: What is the default if none is provided?  If list then i've seen it as default or index, though not a synonym.

Comment: what do you mean list is a reserved word, are you saying a name of a method named list?

Comment: @AbraCadaver  I was thinking of the same, and then can use what ever makes sense to the dev, but it doesn't give much flexibility.

Comment: I think index really is a pretty good word for it, actually.

Comment: ^^ `"index"` or `"all"`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix.  `public method list()` won't work (I am pretty sure).

Comment: why not just call a list a list?

Comment: why are you directly exposing your classes and not an api?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix  Yes, I know the issues, but please forgive me and keep to the question.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Was also thinking of all, and likely the way I might go.  Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 - do you? Anyway, see my solution as you can use list if you know how.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all directly exposing your class methods is probably not the best way to set things up.  As for list being a reserved word, why limit yourself by not using an api.

At some point in your application you will need some logic, right.  So why not just

```
  switch( $_GET['mode'] ){
        case 'list':
            do something
        break;
  }
```

In fact its better to use a class constant, for this like

```
  Class::MODE_LIST = 'list';
```

Besides if you really want to name it list you can, use `__call` like so.

```
class API {

    const MODE_LIST = 'list';
    const MODE_TASK = 'task';           
    const MODE_EDIT = 'edit';   


    public function __call($method, $args){
        switch($method){
            case self::MODE_LIST:
                return $this->_list( $args );
            break;
            case self::MODE_TASK:

            break;
            case self::MODE_EDIT:

            break;
            default:
                ///error  -- do some error reporting.
        }   
    }


    protected function _list( $args ){

    }


}

$API = new API();

$API->{$_GET['mode']}();
```

Comment: Hi Artistic.  Not a bad ideal  by just adding a prefix such as `MODE_` or `_` or whatever, and be consistent.  Let me give it some thought.  Thank you.  PS.  Yes, I see the issues, but doing this solution exposes the same thing.  Just think that one must way the pros (simplicity) and cons (keeping everything from the user even if it won't help them).

Comment: The advantage of using a constant is say latter you decide I don't want to call it edit but update,   Then you just change the value of the constant and no other code changes are needed.  That's the advantage of abstraction.

Comment: Abstraction or obfuscate :)  Regardless, I will likely follow your suggestion.  Thanks

Comment: Not obfuscate, that obscures the meaning.  Abstraction separates it.  Two different ideas.  In fact my example above should would with `$API->list()`, which is hardly obfuscated.

Comment: Well, I think you have a good idea and will definitely upvote, but can't really select without changing the question.  Thank you for your advise.